# Why custom hook function works on update too?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I've made a simple hook in WordPress that runs a function. I thought that using `publish_"custom_post_type_name"`, will trigger the function only when a new post from that custom post type is published. But it doesn't seem to be the case. The function is called even when I update the post. How to call the function only when a post is published for the first time?

My hook:

```php
add_action('publish_news', 'notification');
function notification(){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because the post status is `draft` before being published. You can make a condition in the notification method to check the status of the post, like this:

```
add_action('publish_news', 'notification');
function notification($post){
  global $post;
  if($post->post_status == 'draft'){
      //do something here
  }
}
```

And this will trigger what you want to do only when the post is published.